# How can the "static type" and "dynamic type" be different?

Tags: types, nim-lang

According to the Nim manual, the variable type is a "static type" while the actual value the variable points to in memory is the "dynamic type".

How is it possible they can be different types? I thought assigning the wrong type to a variable would be an error.

Answer (score 8):

```
import typetraits

type
  Person = ref object of RootObj
    name*: string
    age: int

  Student = ref object of Person # a student is a person
    id: int

method sayHi(p: Person) {.base.} =
  echo "I'm a person"

method sayHi(s: Student) =
  echo "I'm a student"

var student = Student(name: "Peter", age: 30, id: 10)
var person: Person = student # valid assignment to base type
echo person.repr # contains id as well
echo name(person.type) # static type = Person
person.sayHi() # dynamic type = I'm a student
```